# What did Nicky mean by this?

Tags: dialogue, casino

In [*Casino*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112641/), when Nicky talks of the diamonds he has stolen and sent to be appraised he says that

> Some of these stones got a lot of niggers in them.

What does he mean by this?

Comment: It is most likely misused in your quote to mean dark *inclusions* which are particles within a diamond that reduce its value.

Comment: yeah, Nicky has a thief's understanding of jewelry and knows that diamonds should not have imperfections although of course artificial diamonds are crystal clear whereas even very expensive natural diamonds have some small issues.